# Could a user account with a stolen password compromised entire WP site?

Tags: security, password, hacked

Assuming a user with Subscriber role account with a weak password has been hacked. So, can someone use this account to compromise a WP site?

Comment: If a plugin has a "privilege escalation" vulnerability, then the hacker could use the account to get a higher level of access, but it depends entirely on the nature of the vulnerability. It's been known to happen. The only way to be safe is to use plugins from trusted sources and to keep them up to date (even if this means paying for legitimate copies of premium plugins!). But on a fresh install of WordPress, a Subscriber cannot do any damage.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Any subscriber can't do any harm to your site even if he wants it.

https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/